# How remove function from this code after first usage this field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_laufzeit_bis').datepicker().on('changeDate', recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_kuendigungsfrist').change(recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_kuendigungsfrist_type').change(recalculate_deadline);

    $('#id_kuendigung_moeglichbis').change(check_reminder_date);
    $('#id_erinnerung_am').datepicker().one('hide', check_reminder_date);
});
```

How remove `check_reminder_date` function from this code after first usage this field? (`#id_erinnerung_am`)

```
$('#id_erinnerung_am').datepicker().one('hide', check_reminder_date);
```

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you want the event to be handled only once, am I right?

Comment: @Салман Yes. Only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this way:

```
$('#id_erinnerung_am').datepicker().one('click', check_reminder_date);
```

or might be this one:

```
$('#id_erinnerung_am').datepicker().end().one('click', check_reminder_date);
```

`hide` is not an event use `click` instead.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* Oh, this is what `.one()` should already do. It probably just didn't fire as one of the others already pointed out.

You can set a flag that indicates if the function has already been called previously.

```
var isFirstCall = false;
function check_reminder_date(){
  if (isFirstCall) {
    isFirstCall = false;
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this trick to achieve what you want:

```
//caching the object with id #id_erinnerung_am
var id_erinnerung_am=$('#id_erinnerung_am'); 


//triggering an event on every close of the datepicker

id_erinnerung_am.datepicker({onClose:function(){
id_erinnerung_am.trigger('datePicker.hidden');
});

//binding the event once with the function 'check_reminder_date',
// this function will be executed only once

id_erinnerung_am.one('datePicker.hidden', check_reminder_date);
```